# How are electric water heating elements isolated?

Tags: safety, isolation, underwater

From what I've seen and understood, electric water heating elements are usually copper tubes/pipes with electricity running through them to heat up the surrounding water. I'm not sure if the electricity directly goes through the tubes/pipes though. How do the heating elements make sure electricity only heats up the water and not run through the water, causing unwanted currents through the water instead?

Comment: Have you looked at Wikipedia? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heating_element

Answer (score 4):

The conducting element is isolated from the exterior tube by a ceramic powder spacer layer that serves as an insulator. There is no electrical contact between the tube and the element (or at least, there shouldn't be.)

More here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heating_element

Answer (score 4):

The element is not made of copper (the resistance would way too low).
Normally it'd be nichrome (nickel+chromium) and then enclosed.

This is a straight quote from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heating_element)

> Tubular (sheathed) elements normally comprise a fine coil of nichrome
>   (NiCr) resistance heating alloy wire, that is located in a metallic
>   tube (of stainless steel alloys, such as Incoloy, or copper) and
>   insulated by magnesium oxide powder.

Answer (score 3):

MgO

wiki:

> It is used extensively as an electrical insulator in tubular construction heating elements. There are several mesh sizes available and most commonly used ones are 40 and 80 mesh per the American Foundry Society. The extensive use is due to its **high dielectric strength and average thermal conductivity**. MgO is usually crushed and compacted with minimal airgaps or voids. The electrical heating industry also experimented with aluminium oxide, but it is not used anymore.
>   It is also used as an insulator in heat-resistant electrical cable.

The expansion CTE ought to match or in between the metals used.   Cu and NiCr.

please report back with all values.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

*Figure 1. Heater construction looking from the heater towards the terminal. Source: [Omega - Electric tubular heaters](https://www.omega.co.uk/prodinfo/tubular-heaters.html).*

The magnesium oxide provides electrical insulation while giving reasonably good thermal conduction. The helically coiled wire helps when bending elements and avoids buckling due to thermal expansion.

This [low-tech construction method](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mi7tahGus9I) YouTube video may help. Note in the video the annealing of the tube using very high current at low voltage to make it very hot.

---

**anneal** /əˈniːl/
*verb*

gerund or present participle: annealing

1.
heat (metal or glass) and allow it to cool slowly, in order to remove internal stresses and toughen it.
"copper tubes must be annealed after bending or they will be brittle"

Answer (score 0):

More **modern heaters** like tankless water heaters use **unisolated wire heating elements** that have direct contact with the water. In other words, the tap water itself is the only isolator. There is no danger since tap water has a high resistance. Advantage is faster heat transfer, less losses and less lime stone coating since the thin heating wire is expanding and contracting with temperature changes. So lime stone coatings are automatically blown off.
But they need sophisticated electronics to quickly detect low/no water flow and possible air bubbles, to avoid **overheating**.

See also https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/211847/why-dont-get-i-shocked-in-an-electric-shower-if-the-resistance-makes-contact-wi/268356#268356

Comment: I'm not sure this is correct. Mains voltage electricity in contact with tap water does not sound like it would even be legal in the US or Europe at the very least, and it's _certainly_ not safe. Especially if the heating element breaks.

Comment: You can be very sure this is correct. See  
http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durchlauferhitzer
Seems to be missing in the english and french wikipedia pages.
Citation of the original text in German:
"Das Wasser wird bei vielen modernen Geräten mittels eines Blankdrahtheizelements erhitzt, bei dem die Heizdrähte direkt vom Wasser umspült werden. Das Leitungswasser wirkt isolierend gegenüber den leitenden Teilen, ..."

Comment: It is safe, and those direct inline water heaters are sold and installed since many years all over this planet. But for marketing reasons, the manufacturers are not very much interested to spread the information about using heating wires with direct water contact.
The reason can be seen in this very question plus reactions, since even many technicians do not have enough knowledge to judge the (non-) danger.

Comment: Maybe it's safe while working as intended, but the possible fault conditions seem too dangerous to even consider using.

Comment: Please do some basic research before flagging down and/or criticising any answer/comment.  
Which fault condition is "too dangerous to even consider using"?
"Especially if the heating element breaks" - that is not at all a safety issue.
It just stops working - water is no more heated - but the user will not be in contact with high voltage via the water.

Comment: Many modern tankless water heaters come with direct heating wires, just have some look on the manufacturers sites like Bosch, Stiebel-Eltron, Vaillant, Clage, Kospel, Thermoflow - just to mention a few.
All these manufacturers produce direct water heaters and do sell them in most countries of this planet, f.e. in Europe with its strict safety codes.

Comment: @Hearth  Please delete or edit your comments in order to not misinform/confuse other readers, who vote down my answer or comments based on your wrong statements.
Just google for "bare wire water heater".  
As an example, in this description it reads
" Additional Information  Uses bare-wire technology for fast and economic heat up", just scroll down this page: 
http://www.zipwater.co.uk/shop/hot-water/zip-inline-instantaneous-hot-water-heater-3kw-es3

Comment: Be cool, man! All of us get occasional downvotes and they're not necessarily from those who wrote critical comments. Instead expand your answer to explain how electrocution is avoided in, for example, a shower. I had never heard of bare wire water heating until today.

Comment: @Transistor A downvote is completely ok and acceptable if it is based on facts, but here it is based on total wrong and misleading information ("it's certainly not safe").
And this can be checked within a few seconds by a search for e.g. "bare wire water heater".
Shouldn't we all be interested to stop spreading wrong information asap if it is so evident and obvious and crystal clear?

Comment: We have no idea what the downvote was based on. It might be by the commenter, by someone who agreed with the comment or they might not have liked your username, be having a bad day or hit it by accident.

Comment: @Transistor The probability is very high that readers get influenced by that totally wrong statements.
Again: should we not correct/eliminate totally wrong information on stackexchange? 
Especially in this case:
1st wrong statement: "it's certainly not safe"
Then this info is corrected, references/wikipedia pages, company names are given.
And now, instead of doing some research, instead of correcting/eliminating that wrong statement, the same commenter insists on his wrong statement by a 2nd similar comment:
"... the possible fault conditions seem too dangerous to even consider using"
?

Comment: @xeeka I didn't even downvote it. And it's certainly not evident and obvious and crystal clear. The only source you linked is written entirely in a language I don't speak, and other than that you're asking us to rely on the words of one random person on the internet (you) who we've never even heard of before. From my knowledge of electrical engineering, this seems extremely unsafe, and none of what you've said has made it seem any less unsafe as you just continue to say "it's perfectly safe!" without any supporting evidence (again, except for the one article in a language I don't know).

Comment: @xeeka Oh, you did actually link another source, missed that at first, but it's one I would consider wholly unreliable as it's trying to sell you the thing--of course they wouldn't say anything about it being unsafe if they could get away with the omission.

Comment: 1. I never said you downvoted my answer/comments.
2. "...a language I don't speak..."
It is a wikipedia page which can be translated into english via google. 
3. The internet is full of evidence, just do a search! I never asked to rely on me, because I knew you would never believe me. Therefore I did ask to do your own research. But obviously you did not. 

Many shipped water heaters come with bare wire heating elements. But again you write "...this seems extremely unsafe..."
Again: Do your own research. And only after your research on the subject, publish any comment on this subject.

Comment: Of course, Siemens, Hyco, Zipwater etc etc. (see above) are all unreliable and are selling extremely unsafe water heaters in markets like Sweden, UK, US, Canada, Switzerland, Germany, France, Austria etc. In all those countries it is a piece of cake to fake all necessary safety tests, labels and approvals. 
Of course as result, there are many cases of electrocuted users, and of course, these companies bribe the 1st responders, the clinics, police, the medical examiners and all other parties involved to not disclose the huge danger of those bare wire water heaters. Of course.

Comment: @Transistor
"...Instead expand your answer to explain how electrocution is avoided in, for example, a shower." 
In my answer is only one link to another stackexchange site. In that page I answered a certain question. Guess what you will find there?